# Unable to access local server via domain

Tags: cisco, routing, router, lan, wan

I have a lan server with websites that need to be accessed remotely and locally via domain names.

The domain dns is setup to my ISP static ip, and router's firewall is open on port 80 and is forwarding to the static Lan ip of my server. The only issue is I can't access the server using the domain name when I'm on the same local network as the server, everything remotely works.

What should be configured on my router so that I can access these websites on my server regardless if I'm local or not?

cisco rv320

Comment: What is the router model and configuration?

Comment: You edited the question to include the router model but not the configuration. The easiest thing to do is to have the local DNS server return the local address, but DNS, as a protocol above OSI layer-4 is explicitly off-topic here. You could also, edit your local hosts file on your computer, also off-topic because it is a host configuration.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more likely that DNS name is pointing towards external IP address, and NAT is in use.

I would suggest to use

1. Split DNS
2. Hairpinning

Answer (score 0):

I face the same last year ,in my case it was due to port blocking by default windows firewall.
DNS server runs on port 53, which is blocked by default in Windows 7.

I added rule for allowing port 53 on machine where BIND is installed. For doing this,

Open cmd with admin rights.
Execute >netsh firewall add portopening ALL 53 DNS-server